# Computing the effect size of a Level 2 predictor in HLM

Tags: multilevel-analysis, effect-size

I am looking for advice on computing effect sizes for Level 2 predictors in HLM models.

I found this documentation: https://ssicentral.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/FAQ_Effect_sizes.pdf, but am unsure how to apply it to my analysis. I conducted a 2-level random intercept and slope model with longitudinal data (2 measurement timepoints nested within individuals) in HLM. My model includes a binary Level 1 predictor, a binary level 2 covariate, and a continuous Level 2 predictor of interest.  I would like to obtain effects sizes for the level-2 predictor's influence on the intercept (i.e., baseline measurement point) and slope (i.e., change in measurements from baseline to follow-up). Would I compute the R2 of my final model and compare it the R2 of a random intercept and slope model that only excludes the level 2 predictor?
How would I compute total variation (as shown on the last page of the documentation under "Conclusion") for a model such as mine?

Comment: Hi, welcome to CV! Commenting because I'd also like to see an answer to this, as computing effect sizes from multilevel models is difficult. I think your idea of comparing R-squared's seems reasonable, but there is no accepted standard way of computing R2 from a multilevel model (Nagakawa method is probably most often used). Another way would be to standardize your L2 variable beta using the "pseudo" standardization method, but that is also controversial.